# Translate one table structure to other on Java

Tags: java, algorithm, stream, structure, translate

I have following case.

Given table:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgConstructor
class OldRow {

  String type;
  String name;
  int number;
}
```

```
List<OldRow> oldTable
```

| type | Name | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Alex | 15 |
| 8 | Alex | 17 |
| 9 | Alex | 15 |
| 7 | John | 33 |
| 8 | John | 44 |
| 9 | John | 54 |

Need to translate it to following structure using java 11+

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgConstructor
class NewRow {

String Name;
  int type7;
  int type8;
  int type9;
}
```

```
List<NewRow> newTable
```

| Name | type7 | type8 | type9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 15 | 17 | 15 |
| John | 33 | 44 | 54 |

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was playing with groupingBy but not successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before giving you a way to do it, I want to emphasize a few cosmetic errors I see in your code.

- Your java **variable names should start with lower-case letters**, and names with **capital first letters are used for Class namings**.
- You should indent your code properly so that you (*and other readers*) can see the code blocks better

I couldn't find an elegant solution with fewer lines, so someone might post it in the future but this will work for you. I will first share the code, and then explain the solution below.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgConstructor
class OldRow {

    String type;
    String name;
    int number;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgConstructor
class NewRow {

    String name;
    int type7;
    int type8;
    int type9;

    public void printPretty() {
        System.out.println(this.name + " " + this.type7 + " " + this.type8 + " " + this.type9);
    }
}


public class MainClass {
    
    public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<OldRow> oldRows = new ArrayList<>();
        
        oldRows.add(new OldRow("8","Alex",17)); 
        oldRows.add(new OldRow("7","Alex",15)); 
        oldRows.add(new OldRow("9","Alex",15)); 
        oldRows.add(new OldRow("7","John",33)); 
        oldRows.add(new OldRow("8","John",44)); 
        oldRows.add(new OldRow("9","John",54)); 
        
        Map<String,Integer> type7Map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,Integer> type8Map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,Integer> type9Map = new HashMap<>();
        
        oldRows.forEach(oldRow -> {
            if(oldRow.type.equals("7")) 
                type7Map.put(oldRow.getName(), oldRow.getNumber());
            if(oldRow.type.equals("8")) 
                type8Map.put(oldRow.getName(), oldRow.getNumber());
            if(oldRow.type.equals("9")) 
                type9Map.put(oldRow.getName(), oldRow.getNumber());
        });
        
        List<NewRow> newRows = oldRows.stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(OldRow::getName))
            .map(oldRow -> new NewRow(
                    oldRow.name,
                    type7Map.get(oldRow.getName()),
                    type8Map.get(oldRow.getName()),
                    type9Map.get(oldRow.getName())
                ))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
            
        for(NewRow newRow : newRows) {
            newRow.printPretty();
        }

    }
}
```

The first part of the main is to create the `OldRow` instances you have in your example. Then 3 maps are created to keep *type7*, *type8*, and *type9* values for each name. Since you only have these 3 types; we can use a static number of maps.

These maps are filled by iterating over the `oldRows` list, then `NewRow` entities are filled into a new array by streaming the `oldRows` list and looking up type values from *maps*.

Finally, the print statements, so that you can see what is the last state of the `newRows` array.

Comment: Thanks gsan. I will fix cosmetic errors in my question. Now I am going to try  your suggestion.

Comment: Here I posted simplified question. But I adapted for my real code and it works. Awesome!